# html two Select in a form clause where the 2nd select values depend on the first one

Tags: select, conditional-statements, clause

I have a little question. I want to perform if its possible two select list options in html ( inside a form ) where the option values of the second one depends of what you tried on the first one. I don't know if doing two selects is the best way or i should do it with a radio.

I have the code here for a better explanation :

```
<select name="usuaris">
    <option value="select" selected="selected">Escull un grup de facturació</option>
    <option value="abonat">Facturació abonats</option>
    <option value="client">Facturació clients eventuals</option>
    <option value="valid">Facturació de transaccions validades</option>
</select>



<select name="temps">
    <option value="select" selected="selected">Escull un rang de temps</option>
    <option value="zero">Últimes 24 hores</option>
    <option value="un">Últim mes</option>
    <option value="dos">Últim trimestre</option>
    <option value="tres">Últim any</option>
    <option value="cuatre">Sempre</option>
</select>
```

In this case, if you try in the first one select the value "abonat" you should only have the options "ultim mes" and "ultim any" in the second one.

Anyone knows how to do it ? Maybe I should change to another format ( radio ? ) o it's possible and easy to do with jscript ?

Thanks to all !